# Form data not being passed to Controller when adding form data from view

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm trying to submit a bunch of form data that has been imported from a .csv file and I'm losing the data when I submit the form.

I check the POST request in Chrome Dev Tools and the data is in the POST request, but if I `debug($this->data);` in the controller, it's empty.

Here is some relevant code:

admin_add_template.ctp (my view)

```
<?php for ($i=0; $i < $line - 1; $i++) : ?>

  <?php echo $this->Form->create('ActiveQuoteItem');?>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Quote Template <?= $i; ?></legend>
    <!--                  <input type="hidden" name="xxxx" id="xxxx" value="xxxx" />-->
    <input name="quote_item_id" id="quote_item_id" value="<?php echo $out[$i][2] ; ?>" />
    <input name="estimated_cost" id="estimated_cost" value="<?php echo $out[$i][3] ; ?>" />
    <input name="actual_cost" id="actual_cost" value="<?php echo $out[$i][4] ; ?>" />
    <input name="billed_at" id="billed_at" value="<?php echo $out[$i][5] ; ?>" />
    <input name="inquiry_id" id="inquiry_id" value="<?php echo $the_id; ?>" />
    <input name="active" id="active" value="<?php echo $out[$i][7] ; ?>" />
    <input name="timeline" id="timeline" value="<?php echo $out[$i][8] ; ?>" />
    <input name="timeline_rushed" id="timeline_rushed" value="<?php echo $out[$i][9] ; ?>" />
    <input name="title" id="title" value="<?php echo $out[$i][10] ; ?>" />
    <input name="description" id="description" value="<?php echo $out[$i][11] ; ?>" />
    <input name="category" id="category" value="<?php echo $out[$i][12] ; ?>" />
    <input name="quantity" id="quantity" value="<?php echo $out[$i][13] ; ?>" />
  </fieldset>
<?php endfor; ?>

<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Save', true)); ?>
```

active_quote_items_controller.php  (my Controller)

```
function admin_add_template() {
  if (!empty($this->data)) {
    $this->ActiveQuoteItem->create();
    if ($this->ActiveQuoteItem->saveAll($this->data['ActiveQuoteItem'])) {
      $this->Session->setFlash(__('The active quote item has been saved', true));
      $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index','inquiry_id'=>$this->data['ActiveQuoteItem']['inquiry_id']));
    } else {
      $this->Session->setFlash(__('The active quote item could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In your controller use `$this->request->data` instead of `$this->data`.

Comment: Are using Cakephp 1.3????

Comment: Yes, I just realized that I forgot to include the version I'm using. I am using Cake 1.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the problem was the names of my inputs.

Instead of an input like:

`<input name="quote_item_id" id="quote_item_id" value="<?php echo $out[$i][2] ; ?>"`

It needed to be like:

`<input type="hidden" name="data[<?php echo $i; ?>][quote_item_id]" id="quote_item_id" value="<?php echo $out[$i][2] ; ?>" />`

In other words, I forgot to make it the form into a data array in the view, so when I was trying to debug `$this->data` in the controller, I wasn't getting anything.

Answer (score 0):

You say

```
$this->ActiveQuoteItem->saveAll($this->data['ActiveQuoteItem'])
```

But your form looks to me like it would provide data in a format that would correspond with

```
$this->ActiveQuoteItem->save($this->data)
```